# Can vstest.console filter tests to run by providing traits?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, mstest, vstest

I like running a specific set of tests from Visual Studio filtering them by traits. For example:

[image: Traits on Visual Studio]

My concern is *how I provide trait-based filters to **vstest.console***?

Actually I'm trying to improve a continous integration build using the new scriptable build system on Team Foundation Server 2015 and I'd like to separate test steps based on the software layer or tier (and obviously I've organized my tests by traits using `[TestCategory]` attribute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trial-errors, the answer is **yes, it's possible to provide test filters to `vstest.console`**.

You need to use `/TestCaseFilter` command-line switch. For example, in my case I provided `/TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=rest"`

It's explained on [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx) where it states:

> Run tests that match the given expression.  is of the
>   format =[|]. Example:
>   /TestCaseFilter:"Priority=1" Example:
>   /TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=Nightly|FullyQualifiedName=Namespace.ClassName.MethodName"